# Devise broke by itself? /users/edit goes to 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, routes

When clicking on the User Profile link `edit_user_registration_path` (`http://localhost:3000/users/edit`) which used to work yesterday. Today goes to a 404 error that looks like this.

```
    Routing Error

    No route matches {:controller=>"devise/ideas"}
    Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

I checked `rake routes` and I get

```
           like_idea GET    /ideas/:id/like(.:format)      ideas#like
        comment_idea POST   /ideas/:id/comment(.:format)   ideas#comment
               ideas GET    /ideas(.:format)               ideas#index
                     POST   /ideas(.:format)               ideas#create
            new_idea GET    /ideas/new(.:format)           ideas#new
           edit_idea GET    /ideas/:id/edit(.:format)      ideas#edit
                idea GET    /ideas/:id(.:format)           ideas#show
                     PUT    /ideas/:id(.:format)           ideas#update
                     DELETE /ideas/:id(.:format)           ideas#destroy
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
                root        /                              home#index
```

Which looks about right one can see the correct route for `edit_user_registration_path`
I'm new to Ruby so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not your edit_user_registration_path that is the problem.

If you look at the error message, Rails is looking for an ideas_controller in the devise folder (ie "devise/ideas"). If you don't have a controller there, it means that somewhere you are calling an incorrect path.

Answer (score -1):

`edit_user_registration_path` require user id.

So you need something like `edit_user_registration_path(@user)`

Comment: I had tried that from another answer I found here. Makes no difference. :(

Comment: Interesting, if I do `<%= debug @user %>` I get 

    <pre class="debug_dump">
    --- 
    ...
    </pre>

Which could explain why it's not working, I wonder why though.

Comment: I disagree. if you run `bin/rake routes | grep edit_user_registration` you see that this route does not require an `:id` param (As of devise 3.2 .. 4.2).